# Windows 7 vs Windows 10 - Handling folder names with spaces in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, escaping, windows-10

I'm trying to create a batch script which must run on both `Windows 7` and `Windows 10`. However, there seems to be a difference in the way each handles folder names with spaces and I have to escape them differently.

In particular, on `Windows 7` I'm successfully using the following command:

```
start cmd.exe /k "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\openocd.exe -f %OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts\interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg -f %OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts\target\nrf52.cfg"
```

The `OpenOCD_bin_Path` includes a folder which has spaces in it; the full path it references is:

```
C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\GNU MCU Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-7-20180123-1217\bin
```

However, on `Windows 10` the same line fails and displays the following error:

> 'C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\GNU' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If I change the command to:

```
start cmd.exe /k ""%OpenOCD_bin_Path%"\openocd.exe -f "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%"\..\scripts\interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg -f "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%"\..\scripts\target\nrf52.cfg"
```

it succeeds.

Conversely, if I run that command on `Windows 7`, I get this error:

> '""C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming\GNU' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Notice the extra `""` in front on this version.

TLDR; Is there a way I can make this work on both systems without using a switch to detect which OS is runnning?

Comment: What happens if you use `Start`'s `/D` option? Or perhaps setting the current working directory to the deepest common parent first using, `CD /D` then use `<pathto>\openocd.exe -f interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg -f target\nrf52.cfg`. BTW, `C:\Users\Rafael\AppData\Roaming` can be replaced with `%AppData%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd.exe is silly and removes the starting and ending quotes from the command but there is a hack to defeat it:

```
start cmd.exe /k if 1==1 "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\openocd.exe" -f "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts\interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg" -f "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts\target\nrf52.cfg"
```

Calling cmd.exe from `start` is pointless anyway, just use `start`:

```
start "" "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\openocd.exe" -f "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts\interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg" -f "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts\target\nrf52.cfg"
```

It is important that `%OpenOCD_bin_Path%` is the same on all systems in terms of quotes. You normally don't quote paths set in the environment because it is hard to remove the quotes again when needed.

You can strip the quotes but ideally you should avoid dealing with string manipulation in batch files because of escape issues.

Here is a example that tries to handle both cases:

```
@echo off
goto run_tests

:stripquotes
FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%A IN ('echo.%*') DO set %%~A=%%~B
goto :EOF

:test
call :stripquotes mynewvar %*
echo DEBUG: mynewvar is now %mynewvar%
start "" "%mynewvar%\app.exe" "par am 1" param2 "par am 3"
goto :EOF


:run_tests
set OpenOCD_bin_Path=c:\foo bar\baz
call :test %OpenOCD_bin_Path%

set OpenOCD_bin_Path="c:\foo bar\baz"
call :test %OpenOCD_bin_Path%
```

Comment: If I do the first, it works in Windows 10 but not in 7 (same error as originally), the 2nd doesn't work at all. It creates a popup saying "check the command and try again" or something, and prints the entire (but properly dereferenced) command...

Comment: Are you sure %OpenOCD_bin_Path% is the same on both systems?

Comment: It's not the same, interestingly. On Windows 7, it has double quotes around it, but on Windows 10 it has none. Accessed via "echo". I'll poke around more on Monday, but as far as I know they were created with the exact same command, "setx -m" which is run from another batch file previously.

Comment: It should not have quotes. A incomplete path with quotes is hard to work with. I'll update my code with a version that strips the quotes...

Comment: I was able to adapt your quote-handling script. So far it works on both platforms...will update shortly once I've tested more fully.

Answer (score 0):

Using either of the ideas I provided in my comment should bypass the spaces.

Using `CD /D`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "OpenOCD_bin_Path=%AppData%\GNU MCU Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-7-20180123-1217\bin"
CD /D "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts" 2>Nul || Exit / B
Start "" Cmd /K "..\bin\openocd.exe -f interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg -f target\nrf52.cfg"
```

Or you could try it without explicitly starting `cmd.exe`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "OpenOCD_bin_Path=%AppData%\GNU MCU Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-7-20180123-1217\bin"
CD /D "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%\..\scripts" 2>Nul || Exit / B
Start ..\bin\openocd.exe -f interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg -f target\nrf52.cfg
```

Using `Start /D`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "OpenOCD_bin_Path=%AppData%\GNU MCU Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-7-20180123-1217\bin"
Start "" /D "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%" Cmd /K "openocd.exe -f ..\scripts\interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg -f ..\scripts\target\nrf52.cfg"
```

Or once again without explicitly starting `cmd.exe`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "OpenOCD_bin_Path=%AppData%\GNU MCU Eclipse\OpenOCD\0.10.0-7-20180123-1217\bin"
Start "" /D "%OpenOCD_bin_Path%" openocd.exe -f ..\scripts\interface\ftdi\SuperDongle.cfg -f ..\scripts\target\nrf52.cfg
```

Comment: Ok, the first two work on both Windows 7 & 10, the second two only work on Windows 10.

Comment: Just tested the full thing, none of them will work properly in my application. This is because there are more files that are referenced by the script that live in the original directory. If I call the command either with CD or start it IN %OpenOCD_bin_Path%, it's a different environment so those files aren't found.

It does work in versions where I start the command fully from the calling directory, so unless I change the rest of the script (which throws up more questions) I actually do need to properly dereference the path within the actual command.